# Can't add custom key to existing array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array called "$apptAddons" that I would like to have custom key value pair. My current code to accomplish this is as follows:

```
foreach($decodeaddons as $addons){
            if(in_array($addons->id, $AddonArray)){

                $apptAddons[$addons->id] = $addons->name;
            }           
        }
```

When I do this and I print out the array, it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Marketing Addon [1] => Same Day Delivery )
```

For reference, it should be the following:

```
Array ( [64251] => Marketing Addon [3370] => Same Day Delivery )
```

The `$addons->id` does print out the proper numbers by themselves, it just won't affect the key for each value in the array. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, as that was how I was shown was the way you add a custom key to an existing array.

Update: I should have mentioned before that I am parsing a JSON response from an API call in this particular code, if that changes anything.

Second Update: Here is the var_dump from the if section as requested by x01saa:

```
    object(stdClass)#22 (5) { ["id"]=> int(64251) ["name"]=> string(14) 
"Marketing Addon" ["duration"]=> int(0) ["price"]=> string(5) "50.00" 
["private"]=> bool(false) } object(stdClass)#24 (5) { ["id"]=> int(3370) 
["name"]=> string(17) "Same Day Delivery" ["duration"]=> int(0) ["price"]=> 
string(5) "25.00" ["private"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: `$apptAddons['customKey'] = 'customValue';`

Comment: Try to `var_dump($addons)` in if block and update your question. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this..

```
 foreach($decodeaddons as $addons){
                if(in_array($addons['id'], $AddonArray)){

                    $apptAddons[$addons['id']] = $addons['name'];
                }           
            }
```

Comment: I did try that, it came up with an error "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"